# Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed

Tags: json, swift, google-drive-api, alamofire, decoder

I'm trying to decode json from google drive attachment but it shows the following error:

responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

The JSON:

```
{
 "price" : 5000,
 "item" : "Some item"
}
```

Models:

```
struct Things: Codable {
   let price: Int,
   let item: String
}
```

Request:

```
Alamofire.request("https://drive.google.com/linkhere").responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error : \(error)")
                case .success:
                    print("success!")
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let things = try! decoder.decode(Things.self, from: response.data!)
                    print("things.price : \(things.price)")
                    print("things.item : \(things.item)")
            }
        }
```

This only occurs when i fetch json from google drive attachment (the json is valid).
Are there any difference when fetching json from google drive attachment?

Comment: Can you try the `price` with `Float` instead of `Int`?

Comment: Tried with Float and Double, same error

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now, try to add this in the request `Alamofire.request("https://drive.google.com/linkhere", encoding: 
      JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON`

Comment: still the same error, invalid value around character 0

Comment: Could you check your URL response in the browser?

Comment: `Invalid value around character 0` means the received data is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your response goes in failure case that means api call is having an issue, if your response goes in success state that means it may chances your decoding have some issue.

Failure case:

- Check api in postman
- Check api method(i.e GET or POST)
- Check encoding or content type "application/json"